# Passing Account ID to my Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

As the user goes into an account, there is a custom button that they can click that will redirect them to my Visualforce page.  How can I capture that account id  in my controller?

Thanks

```
public myControllerCBR(){
    breachRecord = new List<wrapperClass>();

    AccountTeamMember uId = [SELECT UserId FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE AccountId =:ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('id') and TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Engineer' limit 1];

    List<User> uName = [SELECT Name, Manager__c, MANAGERID, Email, MOBILEPHONE FROM User WHERE Id =:uId.UserId limit 1];


    for(User rept : uName){
        breachRecord.add(new wrapperClass(rept));
    }

}
```

See button setup: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s197/sh/b7efd476-905f-4660-b281-2b71e6755318/1f05fbd47a9d9ebf227649e2e70c4c10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the button you could the following in the formula editor:

```
/apex/YourVisualForcePage?acctId={!RelantionshipName__c}
```

Depending on if you use a standard controller, extension or custom controller you will then have different options

If you are using a custom controller you need to perform a SOQL query on the id in the controller's constructor.

Getting the id is easy, you match the key of the parameter in the query string like so:

```
ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('acctId')
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, I've a custom controller.  I've added "ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('id')" to my query but keep getting error "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject "

Comment: When adding "/apex/YourVisualForcePage?id={!Account.Id}" to my button and clicking  on it will give me an error "unexpected token Illegal".

Comment: ok, so what you need to set in the url of the custom url is the specific name of the relationship you have between your object and the account object. I will also update the query string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add account Id in the url of your custom buttom.. 
for example:

```
?accid={!AccountId}&retURL=..
```