# Pass id from account button to visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

The new button in Contact related list on the Account page points to a VF page which serves as an extra step to create a new Contact (to require them to enter certain info).

Normally, when the new button is standard, AccountId is valued on the new Contact record.

How can I get that AccountId to my controller so I can set it on the new Contact record?

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: String id = stdController.getRecord().Id;

Comes back as null.

Comment: String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  --- Also null

Comment: So are you wanting to pass the id from vf to your apex controller?

Comment: When the VF page is loaded it will fire the constructor of the controller. I want to have the AccountId available there.

Comment: Can this question that was previosly asked help in any manner?link:https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85584/passing-account-id-to-my-visualforce-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @rony joseph

```
/apex/YourVisualForcePage?acctId={!Account.Id}
```

I created a New Contact button on the Account. Content Source = URL with the above url.

I was getting hung up on trying to do this from a Contact Related List button. I don't think it is possible to get Account Id from a Contact Related List button on the Account detail page. It has to be a Detail Page Button on the Account object.